# What is wrong with my usage of C++ standard library's find?

Tags: c++, templates, std, typename

I'm trying to use the C++ standard library's `find` algorithm like this:

```
  template<class T>
  const unsigned int AdjacencyList<T>::_index_for_node(
      const std::vector<T>& list, const T& node
  ) throw(NoSuchNodeException)
  {
    std::vector<T>::iterator iter = std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), node);
  }
```

When I try to compile, I get these errors:

```
In file included from ../AdjacencyList.cpp:8:
../AdjacencyList.h: In member function ‘const unsigned int Graph::AdjacencyList<T>::_index_for_node(const std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >&, const T&)’:
../AdjacencyList.h:99: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘iter’
../AdjacencyList.h:100: error: ‘iter’ was not declared in this scope
In file included from ../AdjacencyListTest.cpp:9:
../AdjacencyList.h: In member function ‘const unsigned int Graph::AdjacencyList<T>::_index_for_node(const std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >&, const T&)’:
../AdjacencyList.h:99: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘iter’
../AdjacencyList.h:100: error: ‘iter’ was not declared in this scope
../AdjacencyList.h: In member function ‘const unsigned int Graph::AdjacencyList<T>::_index_for_node(const std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> >&, const T&) [with T = int]’:
../AdjacencyList.h:91:   instantiated from ‘const std::vector<T, std::allocator<_Tp1> > Graph::AdjacencyList<T>::neighbours(const T&) [with T = int]’
../AdjacencyListTest.cpp:18:   instantiated from here
../AdjacencyList.h:99: error: dependent-name ‘std::vector::iterator’ is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
../AdjacencyList.h:99: note: say ‘typename std::vector::iterator’ if a type is meant
```

I feel like the "dependent-name ‘std::vector::iterator’ is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type" bit holds the key to understanding what I'm doing wrong, but my pea-brain cannot extract the meaning.

**Update:** I needed to add a `typename`, as per the accepted answer, and also use a `const_iterator`, so the problematic line of code became:

```
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator iter = std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), node);
```

Comment: There is no `std::find` in the STL. The `std` namespace denotes use of the C++ Standard Library. Meanwhile, taking out the use of `std::find` would have narrowed the question down a little; in this case, you have a dependent name.

Comment: One of the rare cases where the *last* lines of the error message contain the most useful information...

Comment: One of the rare cases where an error message from a C++ compiler actually contains a useful, actionable suggestion.  ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes, you are technically correct. For most intents and purposes, STL == C++ standard library, but there are some differences, and I should have been clear.

Comment: You'll also need const_iterator, not iterator.

Comment: Ugh again with the STL/stdlib argument... don't people ever get tired of it?

Comment: @Matteo: I hear you, and actually didn't know that referring to std::find() as an STL algorithm was incorrect in any way. I did look it up, and I guess it is better to be 100% correct. Still "STL find" has a better ring to it than "ISO C++ standard library find"! ;)

Comment: @Josh: actually I was saying that pointing out the usual STL/stdlib argument every time someone writes "STL" instead of "the template part of the standard library" or whatever term is felt as correct in the long run is quite boring and useless.

Comment: @Matteo: The "boring and useless" was the bit I was agreeing with, albeit as politely as I could. ;)

Comment: @Josh: uh, sorry, for some reason I understood the exact contrary. Glad that we agree, then `:)` .

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
std::vector<T>::iterator iter = /* .... */;
```

`iterator` is a dependent name (effectively, it *depends* on the type parameter `T`).  Dependent names are assumed not to name types unless you use `typename`:

```
typename std::vector<T>::iterator iter = /* .... */;
```

For more, consider reading the Stack Overflow C++ FAQ entry ["Where and why do I have to put “template” and “typename” on dependent names?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-template-and-typename-on-dependent-names)

You will also need to use `const_iterator`, since `list` is const-qualified.  You should probably drop the exception specification as well; it's best to ["never write an exception specification."](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm)

Comment: Fantastic answer, James! Actually, it was more of a code review than an answer, but code reviews are always welcome. :)